# How OpenGL ES 2 PAN using gestures

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, pan

How can I implement panning in open-gl. I could not find any answer for it.

Here is my code for GLSurface and Render.

```
public class GLSurface extends GLSurfaceView {

//public static GLRender xRender;
ScaleGestureDetector ScaleDetect;
//MainActivity mMain = (MainActivity) getContext();
//OpenGL XOPL = mMain.xOpenGL;
public static GLRender myGLRender;

public GLSurface(Context context){
    super(context);

    // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
    //setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    myGLRender = new GLRender();
    setRenderer(myGLRender);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    ScaleDetect = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleDetectorListener());
}

private float mPreviousX;
private float mPreviousY;
float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 300;

private long pressStartTime;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

            ScaleDetect.onTouchEvent(e);

            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            switch (e.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:


                    if(!ScaleDetect.isInProgress() && e.getPointerCount() == 1) {

                        float xMoveRange = x - mPreviousX;
                        float yMoveRange = y - mPreviousY;
                        float dx = 0.0f;
                        float dy = 0.0f;
                        float w = this.getWidth();
                        float h = this.getHeight();
                        float NormalizedXRange = xMoveRange / w;
                        float NormalizedYRange = yMoveRange / h;

                        //if (Math.abs(xMoveRange) > w / 100 && Math.abs(yMoveRange) < h / 100){

                            dx = NormalizedXRange * 360;

                            myGLRender.setAngleX(myGLRender.getXAngle() + dx);

                        //}

                        //if (Math.abs(xMoveRange) < w / 100 && Math.abs(yMoveRange) > h / 100){

                            dy = NormalizedYRange * 360;

                            myGLRender.setAngleY(myGLRender.getYAngle() + dy);

                        //}

                            requestRender();

                    }
                    else if (e.getPointerCount() == 3){

                        float xMoveRange = x - mPreviousX;
                        float yMoveRange = y - mPreviousY;

                        myGLRender.setRange(xMoveRange,yMoveRange);

                        requestRender();

                    }

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    pressStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    long pressDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressStartTime;
                    if (pressDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {

                        float Nx = (x - Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getWidth())) * 0.5f) / (Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getWidth())) * 0.5f);
                        float Ny = (y - Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getHeight())) * 0.5f) / (Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(this.getHeight())) * 0.5f);
                        float Nz = 1.0f;

                        myGLRender.setNCoordinate(Nx, Ny, Nz);

                        myGLRender.Selection();

                        requestRender();

                    }

                    break;
            }

            mPreviousX = x;
            mPreviousY = y;

    return true;
}

private float sizeCoef = 1;

public class ScaleDetectorListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    float scaleFocusX = 0;
    float scaleFocusY = 0;

    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
        float scale = arg0.getScaleFactor() * sizeCoef;

        sizeCoef = scale;

        myGLRender.setZoom(sizeCoef);

        requestRender();

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
        invalidate();

        scaleFocusX = arg0.getFocusX();
        scaleFocusY = arg0.getFocusY();

        myGLRender.setFocus(scaleFocusX,scaleFocusY);

        return true;
    }

    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector arg0) {
        scaleFocusX = 0;
        scaleFocusY = 0;

        myGLRender.setFocus(scaleFocusX,scaleFocusY);
    }
}
```

**GLRender**

```
public class GLRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mModelViewMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mTranslateMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mMVPMatrixforCoord = new float[16];
private final float[] mTranslateMatrixCoord = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mModelViewMatrixCoord = new float[16];
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mRSMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mScMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mVRMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mInvMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private static ArrayList<Line> DrLine = new ArrayList<Line>();
private static ArrayList<Point> DrPoint = new ArrayList<Point>();
private static ArrayList<Line> XGridLine = new ArrayList<Line>();
private static ArrayList<Line> YGridLine = new ArrayList<Line>();
private float ratio;
private float Joint1;
private float Joint2;
private float x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;
private float px, py, pz, ps;
private float[] nearN = new float[4];

private Boolean GridOnOff = false;

private float[] Range = new float[4];
private float[] NewRange = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> LineArray =  new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
private static ArrayList<String> L = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> P = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> PointArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
private static ArrayList<String> EmptyLine = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> EmptyPoint = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> UndoL = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> UndoP = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>[] UndoLineArray = new ArrayList[10];
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>[] UndoPointArray = new ArrayList[10];
private Integer CountUndoLine = 0;
private Integer CountUndoPoint = 0;

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Line XLine = new Line();
    XLine.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f / 10, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    XLine.SetColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line YLine = new Line();
    YLine.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f / 10, 0.0f);
    YLine.SetColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line ZLine = new Line();
    ZLine.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f / 10);
    ZLine.SetColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    Line XX1 = new Line();
    XX1.SetVerts(0.11f, -0.02f, 0.0f, 0.13f, 0.02f, 0.0f);
    XX1.SetColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line XX2 = new Line();
    XX2.SetVerts(0.11f, 0.02f, 0.0f, 0.13f, -0.02f, 0.0f);
    XX2.SetColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line YY1 = new Line();
    YY1.SetVerts(-0.02f, 0.11f, 0.0f, 0.02f, 0.11f, 0.0f);
    YY1.SetColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line YY2 = new Line();
    YY2.SetVerts(-0.02f, 0.13f, 0.0f, 0.02f, 0.13f, 0.0f);
    YY2.SetColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line YY3 = new Line();
    YY3.SetVerts(0-.02f, 0.11f, 0.0f, 0.02f, 0.13f, 0.0f);
    YY3.SetColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    Line ZZ1 = new Line();
    ZZ1.SetVerts(0.0f, -0.02f, 0.13f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.13f);
    ZZ1.SetColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    Line ZZ2 = new Line();
    ZZ2.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.13f, 0.0f, 0.02f, 0.11f);
    ZZ2.SetColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    Line ZZ3 = new Line();
    ZZ3.SetVerts(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.13f, 0.0f, 0.02f, 0.15f);
    ZZ3.SetColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mViewMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0.5f + NewRange[0], 0.5f + NewRange[1], 1.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mVRMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mXAngle, 0, 1f, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mYAngle, 1f, 0, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mScMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.scaleM(mScMatrix,0,mScale,mScale,mScale);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mRSMatrix,0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mRSMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0, mScMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVRMatrix, 0, mRSMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelViewMatrixCoord,0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelViewMatrixCoord,0, 0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mTranslateMatrixCoord,0,mModelViewMatrixCoord,0,mRotationMatrix,0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrixforCoord, 0, mVRMatrix, 0, mTranslateMatrixCoord, 0);



    //Matrix.setIdentityM(mVRMatrix, 0);
    //Matrix.multiplyMM(mVRMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mRSMatrix, 0);
    //Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
    //Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mVRMatrix, 0);

    if (GridOnOff) {

        Grid();

        for (Line XGrid : XGridLine) {
            XGrid.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        }

        for (Line YGrid : YGridLine) {
            YGrid.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        }
    }

    Drawer();

    if (DrLine.size() > 0) {
        for (Line LineX : DrLine) {
            LineX.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        }
    }


    if (DrPoint.size() > 0) {
        for (Point PointX : DrPoint) {
            PointX.draw(mMVPMatrix);
        }
    }

    XLine.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    YLine.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    ZLine.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);

    XX1.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    XX2.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    YY1.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    YY2.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    YY3.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    ZZ1.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    ZZ2.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);
    ZZ3.draw(mMVPMatrixforCoord);




}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    ratio = (float) width / height;

    //Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio*10, ratio*10, -10, 10, 1, 9);
    Matrix.orthoM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f);

}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    if (shader != 0){
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            Log.e("XS", "Could not compile shader " + type + ":");
            Log.e("Shade", GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            shader = 0;
        }
    }

    return shader;
}

public static void checkGlError(String glOperation) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        Log.e("XR", glOperation + ": glError " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(glOperation + ": glError " + error);
    }
}

private Float TempMaxPointHolder = 0.0f;
private Float MaxPointHolder = 0.0f;

public Float Scaler(){

    Float TempScaler = 1.0f;
    Double x, y, z, r;

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> MaxPointFinder = PointArray.iterator();

    while (MaxPointFinder.hasNext()){

        ArrayList<String> MaxPoint = MaxPointFinder.next();

        x = Double.parseDouble(MaxPoint.get(1));
        y = Double.parseDouble(MaxPoint.get(2));
        z = Double.parseDouble(MaxPoint.get(3));
        r = Math.abs(Math.sqrt( x * x + y * y + z * z));

        TempMaxPointHolder = r.floatValue();

        if (TempMaxPointHolder > MaxPointHolder){
            MaxPointHolder = TempMaxPointHolder;
        }

    }

    if (MaxPointHolder != 0) {
        TempScaler = 0.9f / MaxPointHolder;
    }
    else {
        TempScaler = 1.0f;
    }

    return TempScaler;
}

public void Drawer(){

    Float Scaler = Scaler();

    Integer Lindex = 0;

    ArrayList<Point> TempDrPoint = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList<Line> TempDrLine = new ArrayList<Line>();

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> Litr = LineArray.iterator();

    while (Litr.hasNext()) {

        L = Litr.next();

        Joint1 = Float.parseFloat(L.get(1));
        Joint2 = Float.parseFloat(L.get(2));

        Iterator<ArrayList<String>> PitrL = PointArray.iterator();

        while (PitrL.hasNext()){

            P = PitrL.next();

            if (Float.parseFloat(P.get(0)) == Joint1) {
                x1 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(1)) * Scaler;
                y1 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(2)) * Scaler;
                z1 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(3)) * Scaler;
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(P.get(0)) == Joint2) {
                x2 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(1)) * Scaler;
                y2 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(2)) * Scaler;
                z2 = Float.parseFloat(P.get(3)) * Scaler;
            }

        }

        Line TempLine = new Line();
        TempLine.SetVerts(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2);
        if (L.get(3) == "0") {
            TempLine.SetColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        else if (L.get(3) == "1"){
            TempLine.SetColor(0.66f, 0.73f, 0.21f, 1.0f);
        }

        TempDrLine.add(TempLine);

        Lindex = Lindex + 1;
    }

    setDrLine(TempDrLine);

    Integer Pindex = 0;

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> Pitr = PointArray.iterator();

    while (Pitr.hasNext()){

        P = Pitr.next();

        px = Float.parseFloat(P.get(1)) * Scaler;
        py = Float.parseFloat(P.get(2)) * Scaler;
        pz = Float.parseFloat(P.get(3)) * Scaler;
        ps = Float.parseFloat(P.get(4));

        Point TempPoint = new Point();
        TempPoint.SetPointVerts(px, py, pz);

        if (ps == 0.0f) {
            TempPoint.SetPointColor(0.659f, 0.659f, 0.659f, 1.0f);
        }
        else if (ps == 1.0f) {
            TempPoint.SetPointColor(0.68f, 0.07f, 0.32f, 1.0f);
        }

        TempDrPoint.add(TempPoint);

        Pindex = Pindex + 1;

    }

    setDrPoint(TempDrPoint);
}

public volatile float mXAngle;
public volatile float mYAngle;

public void setRange (float XRange, float YRange){

    Matrix.invertM(mInvMVPMatrix,0 , mMVPMatrix, 0);

    Range[0] = XRange;
    Range[1] = YRange;
    Range[2] = 0.0f;
    Range[3] = 1.0f;

    Log.d("XXX", String.valueOf(XRange));
    Log.d("YYY", String.valueOf(YRange));

    Matrix.multiplyMV(NewRange, 0, mInvMVPMatrix, 0, Range, 0);

}

public void setGridOnOff (Boolean OnOff){
    GridOnOff = OnOff;
}

public Boolean getGridOnOff(){
    return GridOnOff;
}

public ArrayList<Line> getDrLine() {
    return DrLine;
}

public ArrayList<Point> getDrPoint(){
    return DrPoint;
}

public void setDrLine(ArrayList<Line> XDrLine) {
    DrLine = XDrLine;
}

public void setDrPoint(ArrayList<Point> XDrPoint) {
    DrPoint = XDrPoint;
}

public float getXAngle() {

    if (mXAngle > 360 || mXAngle < -360){
        return 0.0f;
    }
    else {
        return mXAngle;
    }
}

public float getYAngle(){

    if (mYAngle > 360 || mYAngle < -360){
        return 0.0f;
    }
    else {
        return mYAngle;
    }

}

public void setAngleX(float Xangle) {
    mXAngle = Xangle;
}

public void setAngleY(float Yangle) {
    mYAngle = Yangle;
}

public volatile float mScale = 1;
public volatile float mXFocus;
public volatile float mYFocus;

public void setZoom(float scale){
    mScale = scale;
}

public void setFocus(float XFocus, float YFocus){
    mXFocus = XFocus;
    mYFocus = YFocus;
}

public float getmScale(){
    return mScale;
}

public float getmXFocus(){
    return mXFocus;
}

public float getmYFocus(){
    return mYFocus;
}

public void setLineArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> XLine){
    this.LineArray = XLine;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getLineArray(){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> TempLine = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> LItr = LineArray.iterator();

    while (LItr.hasNext()){

        ArrayList<String> TempLineInner = new ArrayList<String>(LItr.next());

        TempLine.add(TempLineInner);

    }

    return TempLine;
}

public void setUndoL(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> UndoLine){

    if (CountUndoLine < 10) {
        UndoLineArray[CountUndoLine] = UndoLine;
        CountUndoLine = CountUndoLine + 1;
    }
    else {
        CountUndoLine = 0;
        UndoLineArray[CountUndoLine] = UndoLine;
    }
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> getUndoL() {
    return UndoL;
}

public void setUndoP(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> UndoPoint){
    if (CountUndoPoint < 10) {
        UndoPointArray[CountUndoPoint] = UndoPoint;
        CountUndoPoint = CountUndoPoint + 1;
    }
    else {
        CountUndoPoint = 0;
        UndoPointArray[CountUndoPoint] = UndoPoint;
    }
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> getUndoP() {
    return UndoP;
}

public void setPointArray(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> XPoint){
    this.PointArray = XPoint;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getPointArray(){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> TempPoint = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> PItr = PointArray.iterator();

    while (PItr.hasNext()){

        ArrayList<String> TempPointInner = new ArrayList<String>(PItr.next());

        TempPoint.add(TempPointInner);

    }

    return TempPoint;
}

public ArrayList<String> getEmptyPoint(){
    return new ArrayList<> (EmptyPoint);
}

public void setEmptyPoint(ArrayList<String> EPoint){
    EmptyPoint = EPoint;
}

public ArrayList<String> getEmptyLine(){
    return new ArrayList<> (EmptyLine);
}

public void setEmptyLine(ArrayList<String> ELine){
    EmptyLine = ELine;
}

public void setNCoordinate(float NNx,float NNy,float NNz) {
    nearN[0] = NNx;
    nearN[1] = -NNy;
    nearN[2] = NNz;
    nearN[3] = 1.0f;
}

private float[] v1 = new float[3];
private float[] v2 = new float[3];
private float[] v3 = new float[3];
private float[] v4 = new float[4];
private float[] v5 = new float[4];
private float[] v6 = new float[4];
private float[] v7 = new float[4];
private float[] v8 = new float[3];
private float[] v9 = new float[3];
private float[] NewPoint = new float[4];
private float[] OldPoint = new float[4];
private Boolean PointSelect = false;

}
```